# How to insert list of records using ids?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a class as following need to add people to it, but I just have the id of people, do I need to retrieve all the objects before associating them to myList ?

```
class People{

 private long id;

 private String name;
 ....
}

class myList{

 private long id;

 @OneToMany
 private List<People> people;
 ...
}

class myModel{
  ....
  {
    List long selectedPeople  <<< has ids such as 8 9 7 6 45 6
    myList mylist = new MyList();
    mylist.setPeople(selectedPeople);
    session.save(mylist);
    ...
  }
```

Comment: if you have a  `List<Long>` you can't set something expecting `List<People>`

Comment: do I need to retrieve all of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't do this

```
List<People> toSave = new ArrayList<>();

for(Long id : selectedPeople){
   People people = new People();
   people.setId(id);
   toSave.add(people);
}
myList.setPeople(toSave);
session.save(myList);
```

Also your `People` class would be better as `Person` perhaps.